# Cell.Offset Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie with vba and programming in general, but can generally modify existing code if it is simple enough. I modified a macro that pulls cells from another workbook based on the path defined by another macro I found. I've gotten it to pull in cells correctly based off of Column A. I now need it to pull information based on Column AF (different criteria). I modified it to do so, and successfully, but it copied the 41 following columns (I can't seem to get the offset working correctly) rather than those both proceeding and following.

How can I fix this to do so? 
I apologize for what is likely a bush league question.

```
ThisWB = ThisWorkbook.Name
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
path = GetFileName

        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
            WS.Select
            B = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
            If B = 0 Then
                            Else
                For Each Cell In Range("A1:A" & B)
                If VarType(Cell.Value) <> vbnumber Then
                A = Application.CountA(Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A:A")) + 1
               Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 41)).Copy Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A" & A)
               End If
               Next Cell
            End If
        Next WS
        Wkb.Close False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Wkb = Nothing
Set LastCell = Nothing
Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Select
```

Comment: Do you want to copy ALL the cells proceeding and following?

Answer (score 1):

Your function call:

```
Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 41)).Copy 
    Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A" & A)
```

Is doing the following; `Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 41)` means select a range that stretches from the current cell (the first argument) to a cell that is 0 rows off, and 41 columns to the right of your current cell (the second argument).

This is why you are selecting the following 41 columns.

Instead, to select the preceding, and following cells, effectively the entire row, you can try:

```
Range(Cell).EntireRow.Copy Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A" & A)
```

This will copy the entire row from your sheet to the Complaints Worksheet, starting at the required row, column A

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error: "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed".



`For Each Cell In Range("AF1:A" & B)
                    If Cell.Value = True Or Cell.Value = "written" Then
                    A = Application.CountA(Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A:A")) + 1
                    Range(Cell).EntireRow.Copy Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A" & A)`

Comment: @user1872838 What is the value of A? I have just tested this as working in Excel 2010.

Comment: `A = Application.CountA(Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A:A")) + 1`

Sorry if this is trivial.

Comment: @user1872838 Not at all! Does changing the line to `WS.Range(Cell).EntireRow.Copy Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A" & A)` make any difference? It's important to work out which part isn't working for you. What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Offset does what the name implies, and returns a selection the same size as the original.
One can then restrict it with the Rows() and Columns() methods.

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but

```
Cell.Offset(0,41).Copy
```

will copy the cell 41 columns to the right of the range Cell.

It's not a good idea to name variables A and B in an Excel macro, too easy to confuse them with columns A and B.